# Coupon Codes with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

How do i store a coupon code in the parse server and when the user enters the coupon code that he purchased, It discounts it from the price of the product that he's purchasing?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class called "Coupon", have the objectId as coupon code. I would also include a "balance" field to register coupon balance. 
When a user redeems it for purchase, you can link this coupon the the purchase, and deduct the balance.
the code would look something like this:

```
purchase["coupon"] = coupon;
purchase["amount"] = purchase["amount"] - coupon["balance"];
purchase.saveInBackground();
```